# want banner and image look like a single image with same width but should be responsive according to all browser sizes

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://www.giulietta-del-conte.com/img/GdC-Logo.jpg" alt="image" class="ri">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgIgacR7lL5NvgHyajZEeWlam9pUfmTMe749qDew4Lw11MDwmi" alt="banner" class="r2">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS: made an improved version of what i posted before.

```
div { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height:80%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img.ri {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img.r2 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

media queries for orientation.

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  div, img.ri, img.r2 { max-width: 90%; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  div, img.ri, img.r2 { max-height: 100%; }
}
```

But still not working when browser is stretched horizontally. images appear in scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

*ANSWER UPDATED following comments*
As far as I understand your question, I think you want something like this:

HTML:

```
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="inner">
        <img src="https://www.giulietta-del-conte.com/img/GdC-Logo.jpg" alt="image" class="ri">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgIgacR7lL5NvgHyajZEeWlam9pUfmTMe749qDew4Lw11MDwmi" alt="banner" class="r2">
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
 width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  max-width:100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.ri, .r2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/qNwGLv

NB: this solution uses Viewport units to size the .wrap please check your browser support requirements http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units . If you need to support more browsers you will need to use a javascript solution for sizing the .wrap div, something like:

JS:

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
 $('.wrap').css({
        'height': y + 'px'
    });
```

Comment: nope! i want the images to resize and fit the screen according to the way i resize my browser. If you decrease the size of the browser the image should be centered as per the display width available meaning responsive in whatever screen size it is, it should fit into that itself. Hope i was able to make myself clear.

Comment: No sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. Do you have any design visuals?

Comment: check out this link: [link](https://www.giulietta-del-conte.com/). It is responsive as well as center no matter how you resize the browser. But the code used here is complicated. I am looking for something much simpler, which does the same response as depicted on the link. Thanks.

Comment: nope still not responsive. Scrolling to be avoided even when the screen gets smaller. If you refer to the link you can see there are no scrolls. Even if you resize the browser to the minimum width and height you still get the full picture in that small visible space without any scrolling. i want to shrink the images in whatever area the browser is resized into.  It should fit into that much space only.  No scrolls should be there.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm going to stop helping you now. I can't understand what you're trying to achieve, or for what purpose.

Comment: It's ok. If you would have opened the link you would have understood what i meant rather than asking it to me so many times.